# How to create a configmap which references the .JS file containing the MongoDB commands?

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes

In Detail, the .JS file contains MongoDB commands like below,

```js
db = db.getSiblingDB('records')
db.createCollection("collection_new");
db.collection_new.insertMany([
  { capped : true, size : 5242880, max : 5000 },
  { capped : false, size : 5242880, max : 8000 },
  { capped : false, size : 5242880, max : 5000 },
  { capped : true, size : 5242880, max : 8000 }
 ])
```

Now, instead of converting this .JS file into a standalone .yaml configmap file, I want to create a configmap which refers to the .JS file. Also, I do not want to add the raw data inside the configmap because the above commands are just a small part of the JS file. The main file contains approx. 400-500 lines.

Comment: If you're using Helm as your deployment tool, it can [import files into a ConfigMap](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/accessing_files/), with the caveat that they need to be physically located within the Helm chart.  I might run this as a separate Job, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot make reference to a file from a configmap. As suggested in the comments, you can use an [Helm template which make reference to a file](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/accessing_files/):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: my-configmap
data:
  mongo-commands.js: |-
    {{ .Files.Get "js/mongo_commands.js" }}
```

Note that:

- The directory `js` is at the root of the Helm chart.
- Charts must be smaller than 1M because of the storage limitations of Kubernetes objects.
- Files in `templates/` cannot be accessed.
- Files excluded using `.helmignore` cannot be accessed.